# how to render output in shiny with newly add column

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build sample shiny app to gain some practical knowledge and now I am stuck with below scenario. please help me to address my problem.

scenario:- I have a data frame dt (name, salary, hike_percent) and would like to add new calculated columns from shiny frontend, so that new columns get added to existed data frame(dt) and display as soon as I click "Add new column". Below is the code to perform the same action. Unfortunately it's not working as expected.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)

dt <- data.table('name' = c('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'),'Salary' = c(1000, 1500, 2500),'hike_percent' = c(0.10, 0.13, 0.25))

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel( prettyCheckboxGroup(inputId = "columns",label = "exported list of columns",choices = unique(names(dt))
    )),
  mainPanel(
    br(),
    div(style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:top left; width: 300px;", textInput("newcolumnname", "new column name")),
    div(style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:top centered; width: 500px;", textInput("formula", "enter formula here")),
    div(style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:top right; width: 100px;", actionButton("addnewcolumn", "Add new column")),
    uiOutput("renderui"),
    DT::DTOutput("data_tbl")
  )
))
#SERVER
server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  reactive_string <- eventReactive(input$addnewcolumn, { 
    f_name <- req(input$colname)
    f_value <- req(input$formula)
    expr <- bquote(.(as.name(f_name)):= .(as.name(f_value)))
    dt[,eval(expr)]
    dt
    # f_name <- req("Save3")
    # f_value <- req("Salary")
    # expr <- bquote(.(as.name(f_name)):= .(as.name(f_value)))
    # dt[,eval(expr)]
    # dt
    })
  output$renderui <- renderUI({ reactive_string()})
  reactive_string2 <- eventReactive(input$addnewcolumn, { (dt) })
  output$data_tbl <- DT::renderDT({ reactive_string2() })
}
#Run the Shiny App to Display Webpage
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pAUF.png
```

Comment: What is the expected input for `formula`?

Comment: Formula can be either calculation of existed columns or simple int or string

Comment: ok, but then you need to put more work into your `fun_newcolumns`. `input$formula` returns a string, but `mutate` expects a vector of length 1 or a function that generates a vector of the same length as the rows of the df

Comment: Thanks Starja for your inputs. Now I am trying to correct the function to capture user inputs from shiny and pass to function, unfortunately below function only working correctly when variable don't have the value in double quotes, if variable passed in double quotes printing same as it is.

Comment: dt <-
  data.table(
    'name' = c('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'),
    'Salary' = c(1000, 1500, 2500),
    'hike_percent' = c(0.10, 0.13, 0.25)
  )

my_function <- function(data,newcolumnname,formula) {
  quo_formula <- enquo(formula)
  quo_newcolumnname <- enquo(newcolumnname)
  new_col <- paste0(quo_newcolumnname)[2]
  dt2 <- data %>% mutate(!!new_col := noquote(!!quo_formula))
  dt2
}

my_function(dt,"new salary","Salary*hike_percent")
my_function(dt,"new salary","500*20")

Comment: Dear experts kindly let me know if i am not able to explain my scenario clearly, will try in different way. My end goal is add new calculated columns to existed data frame from shinyapp UI.

Comment: Some how i am trying to handle my scenario in different way. Could you please let me know why below code not working when i pass the 2 text box values from shiny UI and same working with hard coded values. really i ma stuck here, couldn't move further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly clear as to what you are looking for as just `formula` is named.  The following code adds a new column based on `Salary` column.  You can modify to your needs.

```
dt <- data.table('name' = c('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'),'Salary' = c(1000, 1500, 2500),'hike_percent' = c(0.10, 0.13, 0.25))

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel( prettyCheckboxGroup(inputId = "columns",label = "exported list of columns",choices = unique(names(dt))
  )),
  mainPanel(
    br(),
    div(style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:top left; width: 300px;", 
        textInput("newcolumnname", "new column name")),
    div(style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:top centered; width: 500px;", 
        numericInput("formula", "Multiply Salary", min=0, max=1000, value=1)),
    div(style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:top right; width: 100px;", 
        actionButton("addnewcolumn", "Add new column")),
    DT::DTOutput("data_tbl")
  )
))
#SERVER
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  reactive_dt <- eventReactive(input$addnewcolumn, { 
    if(input$newcolumnname!="" && !is.null(input$newcolumnname) && input$addnewcolumn>0){
      newcolval <- dt$Salary*as.numeric(input$formula)
      newcol <- data.frame(newcolval)
      names(newcol) <- input$newcolumnname
      dt <<- cbind(dt,newcol)
    }

    dt
  })
  
  output$data_tbl <- DT::renderDT({reactive_dt()})
  
}
#Run the Shiny App to Display Webpage
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks YBS for modified code, your understanding is correct, only change i ma looking for is instead of "newcolval <- dt$Salary*as.numeric(input$formula)" this line i am expecting newcolval <- dt$input$formula (where input$formula value can be Salary * hike_percent or Salary * 1000 or input$formula*1000000). Now i have updated your code with following statement "newcolval <- dt$input$formula" but getting following erro "'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]"

Comment: You need to define what your formula will be and define it with a drop-down list to pick the variable and a numericInput to multiply.  Arbitrarily allowing users to write a text as formula will lead to numerous errors and you need to account for any possibility.  I have just shown how to add new column - as stated in your OP.  Now you need to define appropriate formula that you wish to display.  You can pick the variables as dt[[as.name(input$formula)]] only if an existing variable in dt is selected (from a drop down list). Then you can multiply it with a numericInput variable (1 or 1000).

Comment: good idea. Let me try from my end. Thanks for your inputs YBS really appreciate.